# Azure Portal - Cannot access SQL Server Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal

I created a SQL Server Instance and Database through Azure.
Then over the course of development I deleted and recreated that database through SQL Management Studio.
I can still see the Database under the SQL Server Instance but when I click on it I get:

```
Access denied
You do not have access
Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.
```

Note: This only occurs on the new Azure Portal. The old one works fine, but it will soon be going away.

Any idea what I need to do to get access in the new Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't even aware you could delete and create Azure SQL Databases from SSMS...

I'm guessing it has created the DB with different credentials then. If you have Owner/Contributor/Reader role in the resource group where the DB is you should be able to access it. Even more so if you have one of those roles on the subscription/are an admin.

You need to check your roles.

Comment: For future reference, you should do the deletion/creation of databases through Azure's APIs. So use e.g. the Portal, PowerShell, xPlat CLI.

Comment: DB is about 1/4 GB and actively used so trying to avoid deleting and recreating. I created a test DB and under Security for that database I have the same dbo, guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and sys Users that my other database has. The SQL Server instance (above my databases) has my azure login user. Don't see anything security-wise in the new db that isn't in my old one. Can't see passwords for those 4 users, but don't think that's it.

Comment: That same azure login user exists under the master database under security. Must be somewhere in master DB tables.

Comment: You have to check Users section in Azure Portal for your resource group/subscription like I said and check your roles there. The fact that your Azure login has access to the DB e.g. through SSMS is completely separate from being able to access it in the Portal. For that you have to have a role that allows doing that on the subscription, resource group, or resource.